# CodeIgniter - Combine form validation and file upload

Tags: php

I would like to create file upload with some fields for title and summary of upload file. I have also looked at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5177421/codeigniter-form-validation-and-file-upload-data) question, but I don't understand it completly.

```
function someform()
{
   // some variables for fields
   ($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE)
   {

   }
   else
   {
      // how to check if the file was uploaded?
   }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should check validation for all the other fields other than the file upload. After the validation succeeds there, check the files. Example:

```
function someform()
{
   // some variables for fields
   ($this->form_validation->run() == TRUE)
   {

       $config['upload_path'] = './uploads/';
       $config['allowed_types'] = 'gif|jpg|png';
       $config['max_size'] = '100';
       $config['max_width'] = '1024';
       $config['max_height'] = '768';

       $this->load->library('upload', $config);


       $fileTagName = 'myfile'; // e.g <input type='file' name='myfile' />    
       if ($this->upload->do_upload($fileTagName))) {
           //Success in validation of all fields.
       }
       else {
           //Failed to upload file.
           echo $this->upload->display_errors('', '');
       }
   }
   else
   {
      //Other fields failed.
   }
}
```

Comment: Which function do I have to use in view - form_open(), form_open_multipart() or both?

Comment: You should use 'form_open_multipart'.